# How do i draw to an existing opengl color attachment?

Tags: c++, qt, opengl-es

I am using QtOpenGL ES 3.0 with a v4l2 video device.  Using this function...

GLuint QOpenGLFramebufferObject::takeTexture(int colorAttachmentIndex)

I can grab the GLuint and in my mind, I should be able to draw to it.  I have a V4L2 buffer which is in a void* buffer.  I need to place this buffer into the color attachment in my render loop.  I have seen a lot of references on normal API transitions using glTexImage2D().  So I have this...

```
//.h

QOpenGLFramebufferObject * m_fbo;
GLuint                     m_fboColorAttachment;

//.cpp
//...init code... 

m_fbo = new QOpenGLFramebufferObject ( D1_WIDTH, D1_HEIGHT );
glBindFramebuffer ( GL_FRAMEBUFFER, m_fbo->handle () );  // read and write
m_fbo->addColorAttachment ( D1_WIDTH, D1_HEIGHT );

//...end init code...
//...render loop... 

glBindFramebuffer ( GL_FRAMEBUFFER, m_fbo->handle () );  // read and write
m_fboColorAttachment = m_fbo->takeTexture ();     
glBindTexture ( GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_fboColorAttachment );

glTexImage2D ( GL_TEXTURE_2D,               // Type of texture
               0,                           // Pyramid level ( for mip-mapping ) - 0 is 
                                            //the top level
               GL_RGBA,                     // Internal colour format to convert to
               m_nWidth,                    // Image width
               m_nHeight,                   // Image height
               0,                           // Border width in pixels ( can either be 1
                                            //or 0 )
               GL_RGB,   //GL_RGB565,       // Input image format ( i.e. GL_RGB, GL_RGBA, 
                                            //GL_BGR etc. )
               GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT_5_6_5,     // Image data type
               (char*) m_v4l2Device->pool->buffers[ nIndex ].mem );  // The actual image 
                                                                     //data itself

//check if OpenGL errors happened 

if ( ( enumError = glGetError () ) != GL_NO_ERROR )
{
    qDebug ( "OpenGL error: %d.", enumError );
}
```

I am getting an error. So here is my question, how am I supposed to write to this `GLuint` `from` the `char*` `data`? My goal was to not create a new buffer and attach it as a new color attachment in each render loop. If there is already a color attachment `texture2d` `created`, it seems I should be able to fill it with my new data over and over.

I have seen people create new buffers and attach it and then a render buffer and blah. But I don't see why this is needed if a color `texture2d` `already` `exists`. I want to reuse it with my `v4l2` `char` `buffer` `data`.

Cheers,
Pete

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenGL ES does not support format conversions as part of texture uploads. In the `glTexImage2D()` call, *internalformat* and *format*/*type* need to be compatible, based on tables 3.2. and 3.3 in the ES 3.0 spec.

Based on the values in table 3.3, for the unsized `GL_RGBA` *internalformat*, the only legal *format* is `GL_RGBA`, combined with a type that is one of `GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE`, `GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT_4_4_4_4`, or `GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT_5_5_5_1`.

For the `GL_RGB`/`GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT_5_6_5` *format*/*type* combo you are trying to use, the *internalformat* value needs to be `GL_RGB` or `GL_RGB565`. I would always recommend using the sized *internalformat* values. The unsized values are only supported for compatibility with older OpenGL versions.

Comment: yup, this was it.  i changed my input image format to rgba to match that of the desired image format before using opengl.  a = 1 to be transparent.  this works much better.